# Will old Minolta macro extensions work with a ring adapter on a Sony A6000?

Tags: macro, sony, lens-adapter, sony-nex, minolta

I have a Minolta 35mm MC macro; a 50mm MD macro, and a 100mm macro adapter that attaches to a lens to get macro abilities.

Will these work with a ring adapter on a Sony A6000?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking for a "Minolta MD/MC/SR Rokkor Lens to Sony Alpha E-Mount adapter"? I'm not 100% sure that is what you are asking and I'm not a Sony/Minolta user; but based on limited knowledge can you confirm this for others with greater knowledge to answer?

Comment: I'm wanting to know if they can work with an adapter on any aemount lens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should.  I'm using an MD-NEX adaptor with a Minolta MD lens and it works fine on my sony e-mount camera.

I'm told the MD and MC use the same mount.  So as long as your macro tube is in the same mount, should be ok.